# stability of FTCS scheme for parabolic equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, finite-differences

Can you suggest any method for stability analysis of FTCS scheme for the the following parabolic equation ?

D.E: $u_{t}=a(x,t)u_{xx}+f(x,t,u)$, $0<x<1$, $0<t<T$, $T>0$

BCs: $u_{x}(0,t)+hu(0,t)=0$, $u(1,t)=0$

IC:  $u(x,0)=g(x)$

I consider the von neumann method but it requires that the coefficient must be constant and as far as I know it does not use boundary condition. Can you find  stability condition in Lax-Ricthmeyer sense?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: The method you are about to apply is the following: $$ \frac{u^{n+1}_i- u^n_i}{\Delta t} = a^n_i \frac{u^n_{i+1}-2u_i^n + u^n_{i-1}}{\Delta x^2} + f(x_i,t_n,u_{i}^n), $$ right? I'm afraid the stability of the numerical method will strongly depend on the character of $f$. Is this function known or you mean a general function?

Comment: $f$ is a given function depend on $x,t,u$

Comment: The usual approach I learnt from my teacher was setting $u^n_i = \phi_n e^{i I k \Delta x}$, where $I^2 = -1$ and $k$ is an integer. Then, by substituting this into the original equation you try to come up with an expression for the amplification factor, $|\phi_{n+1}/\phi_n|$, which determines the stability of the numerical method. In you case, I can't figure how to do this because of the unknown form of $f$.

Comment: I am reading the book ''Numerical solution of partial differential equations: Finite difference method by G.D.Smith 3rd. ed.'' and in this book at the page 68 says that '' ıt should be noted that this method (von neumann method) applies only to linear equations with constant coefficients.''. Therefore I couldn't use this method. If this form of $f$ is not applicable assume only that $f$ depends only to $x$ and $t$.